# inside nested loops appending list to a new list gives unexpected result

Tags: python

I have tried to write my error issue in reproducible manner for platform to be seen and guided. I cannot see my logic gap why this error happens.
I have a inner loop which brings new elements while scraping and appends it to list named `list_inner`. Then in outer loop list named `list_outer` appends that new list. But final result gives amount of members right, but elements of list list_outer are same, the last list element of list `list_inner`. How can this happen? If it will be one elemented list I will understand.

```
import random
list_inner=[]
list_outer=[]
for i in range(5):
    for r in range(random.randint(1,10)):
        list_inner.append(r)
        print(r)
    list_outer.append(list_inner)
    print(list_outer)
print(list_outer)
```

I am sharing for two results, as giving idea what is in real and what I was expecting. I got this result:

```
0
1
2
3
[[0, 1, 2, 3]]
0
1
2
3
4
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

But I was expecting this result:

```
[[0,1,2,3],[0,1,2,3,4]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are really two problems here:

- You are not clearing `list_inner` at the end of each outer loop, so it retains all the elements from all the iterations so far
- You are appending `list_inner` directly to `list_outer` instead of appending a copy of `list_inner`. This means that when `list_inner` gets changed, the reference to it that has already been put inside `list_outer` gets changed as well. So you end up with the same thing repeated in `list_outer`.

All you need to do is change your code to copy `list_inner` before appending it, and also clear `list_inner` at the end of each outer loop:

```py
import random

list_inner = []
list_outer = []
for i in range(5):
    for r in range(random.randint(1,10)):
        list_inner.append(r)
    list_outer.append(list_inner.copy())
    list_inner.clear()

print(list_outer)
```

Example output:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], [0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [0, 1], [0, 1, 2, 3]]
```

Comment: What is hard to digest why we need to use in your answer `list_inner.copy` in my asnwer i put it like, `list_outer.append(list(list_inner))`. It is like I tried and it worked. But why there is need to copy or make list of appended data to append it as a list ? Would be grateful if could respond this

Comment: @xlmaster `list_inner.copy()` and `list(list_inner)` do the same thing - make a copy of the list - although using `list_inner.copy()` is better as it makes clear what is actually being done. The reason we need to copy the list is because if we don't, we append a **reference** to `list_inner`, which will also get changed whenever `list_inner` is changed. So when we clear the list and start adding new values, the reference we have put in `list_outer` will also change in the same way. This is why you end up with multiple copies of the same thing in `list_outer`. Copying the list prevents this.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved issue, by adding method list to `inner_loop` before append method and putting list inside outer loop. Here's code

```
import random

list_outer=[]
for i in range(5):
    list_inner = []
    for r in range(random.randint(1,5)):
        list_inner.append(r)
        print(r,list_inner)
    list_outer.append(list(list_inner))
    print('list outer',list_outer)
print(list_outer)
```